# Why can't I become Master of the Thieves Guild?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I did the 4 'special' quests (Imitation Amnesty, Silver Lining, Summerset Shadows, and The Dainty Sload) and even after that I did the Khajit quest thing that was given by Tonilia. I have the guild armor (some said that would be an issue), I have done well over 150 small jobs from Vex and Delvin but I'm still waiting for the quest to become Guild Master to pop up but it's not. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and what I can do to fix the problem without losing my save files.

Comment: You have to complete the main quest line as well as the side jobs in order to become Guild Master - have you done so?

Comment: There are mandatory side quests PER city you have to complete before you get the opportunity to be the master of the thieves guild.

Comment: I did complete it

Comment: I did the main story and the side quests but nothingl0

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already completed all of the missions, you have to speak with Brynjolf if you haven't already tried to. He will call you into the middle of the cistern, then inducting you as thieves guild master.

Answer (score 0):

At some point in the Thieve's Guild quest line, the guild master position opens up.  Is the guild master position opened?  If not, you did not complete the quests.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a way how to start the quest to final rank:

You will need to talk to Brynjolf and he will tell you to go to the Cistern. In Cistern, an elf will talk to you with some other Guild members about your final rank, and you will receive the Guildmaster Armor from Tonilla.

Comment: OPs problem is that this quest does not appear at the start, not how to complete the quest. As such, you do not appear to answer the question.